# Having trouble sorting table with JQuery sort method

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

I am using PHP and JQuery to build a data table, I am using jQuery's `.sort()` method to sort the table. However, it is not working as excepted.

For the text fields, nothing is changed (except that the rows are rendered again).
For the numeric fields, the table sorts in a really weird manner.

[image: Data table sorted by ID]

Clearly the ID does not make sense like this? Here is my JavaScript code:

```
const rows = tbody.find('tr').sort((a, b) => {
    let first, second;
    if ($(e.target).attr('data-order') === 'asc') {
        second = a;
        first = b;
        $(e.target).attr('data-order', 'desc');
    }
    else {
        second = b;
        first = a;
        $(e.target).attr('data-order', 'asc');
    }

    const firstTd = $(first).children().eq($(e.target).attr('data-index') - 1).text();
    const secondTd = $(second).children().eq($(e.target).attr('data-index') - 1).text();

    // Take care of numbers
    try {
        return firstTd - secondTd;
    }
    catch (e) {
        // Value is string
        const value = firstTd.localeCompare(secondTd, "en");
        return value;
    }
}).appendTo(tbody);
```

Here is the source code for my table (I just added two rows):

```html
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <button class="btn btn-light data-table-sort"
                        data-index="1" data-order="asc">
                    id <span class="fa fa-sort" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </button>
            </th>
                <button class="btn btn-light data-table-sort"
                        data-index="3" data-order="asc">
                    Text <span class="fa fa-sort" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </button>
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>72</td>
            <td>af7c16d8f1</td>
            <td>2021-11-26 06:16:55</td>
            <td>
                <form method="POST">
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="72">
                    <input type="submit" name="action" value="Details"
                           class="btn btn-info">
                    <input class="btn btn-primary" name="action"
                           type="submit" value="Edit">
                    <input data-id="72"
                           class="btn btn-danger data-table-delete"
                           name="action" value="Delete" type="submit">
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>7</td>
            <td>bedd6af3ed</td>
                <!-- The same form as previous row -->
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I have made sure that `tbody` contains the correct value. I am also selecting the correct column. The table has to be dynamic and reusable so I can't hardcode everything.

Note: I have already tried appending rows to the table instead of the `<tbody>` element.

Comment: I think you need to sort on `innerText` or `innerHTML`. Like `a.innerHTML`.

Comment: Please add a [mcve]

Comment: @firstlast No. OP uses jQuery, so OP should not use DOM methods/properties with it. Also OP already uses `.text()` to get the text content.

Comment: aww ok, didn't see that. thanks.

Comment: Well @Andreas I hope I could obey but this is all of the code I got. For me, it reproduces the error

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) -> Add a [mcve] that reproduces the problem. A picture is not a [mcve]

Comment: I meant the JS code. The trouble is that the table is being generated by PHP. I can add the source code for the table if you like. Also is there a problem with my code?

Comment: I went ahead and created a sample table and modified the code: https://codesandbox.io/s/jquery-playground-forked-rr1ur?file=/src/index.js:842-846

Comment: @firstlast yes I guess the trouble is with something else. (My mind I guess). Your code produces the exact same result when I tried it for my table.

Comment: Post your table

Comment: Alright I will do it

Comment: Works fine: https://codesandbox.io/s/jquery-playground-forked-rr1ur?file=/index.html. Your table was malformed. I added the missing th tag.

Comment: Sir I will check as soon as I will get back to work. Can you please tell me where was the th added?

Comment: @firstlast the I forgot the <th> while copy pasting code. Thanks for everyone who tried to help. I will try DOM methods instead. Maybe they will work?

Answer (score -1):

You probably need to detach elements since you reattach it again later:

`tbody.find('tr').detach().sort...`

This may need readjustments depending on how jQuery arrays are returned but detaching elements is the main idea and other things should be pretty trivial.

Comment: What is `.detach()` going to change? You don't have to remove the elements from the DOM to sort them.

Comment: That depends on the sorting method. But by the looks of it (uses `attachTo`), it doesn't look in-place.

Comment: Well I tried and the table was empty, then I tried sorting before detaching so I got the previous result (Not sorting correctly)

Comment: _"uses `attachTo`"_ - There's no such thing as `$.attachTo()`.  "jQuery"s `.sort()` is just `Array.prototype.sort()` which is in-place. With "appending" them they will be re-organized in the DOM. That's just how "appending" works with the DOM.

Comment: @Andreas I can understand what you mean. Then the trouble is with sorting part only?

Comment: @Faheem-maker  I just guessed. Looks like your sorting method is inplace then. You should give a reproducible example so we can examine thoroughly.

Comment: @Andreas *`appendTo`. Anyhow like i said earlier `This may need readjustments depending on how jQuery arrays are returned but detaching elements is the main idea and other things should be pretty trivial.`, and that idea I already implied that this suggestion could work or not depending on how arrays are actually managed throughout here, but best I can do is just guess based on his shown methods.

Comment: A guess is not an answer...

Comment: Take note that this is also something to consider: https://api.jquery.com/Types/#ArrayLikeObject.  I wouldn't bother going through complicated questioning so call it whatever you want.  He already gave the best clue which is `appendTo` from an example that has no reproducible code and my suggestion could have sufficed or not.